# Segmentation fault when running "assistant_library_demo.py" using the AIY voice kit and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am a very new programmer and wanted to try out the AIY voice kit that uses Google Assistant API. I have a step-by-step guide that pretty much tells me how to set it up but now when it's up and running the guide tells me to run "assistant_library_demo.py" which is to make sure that the google assistant understands you. I have already done a mic check and sound check which worked perfectly.

However, when I run it I only get

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/AIY-projects-python $ src/examples/voice/assistant_library_demo.py 
Segmentation fault
```

I've tried google but only found out that Segmentation fault means that the program crashed. I am not sure what to do from here since I am not very good at programming. Please let me know if I need to give any more information.

This is the code that I'm trying to run

```
import logging
import platform
import sys

from google.assistant.library.event import EventType

from aiy.assistant import auth_helpers
from aiy.assistant.library import Assistant
from aiy.board import Board, Led

def process_event(led, event):
    logging.info(event)

    if event.type == EventType.ON_START_FINISHED:
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK  # Ready.
        logging.info('Say "OK, Google" then speak, or press Ctrl+C to quit...')

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        led.state = Led.ON  # Listening.

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE:
        led.state = Led.PULSE_QUICK  # Thinking.

    elif (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED
          or event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_TIMEOUT
          or event.type == EventType.ON_NO_RESPONSE):
        led.state = Led.BEACON_DARK

    elif event.type == EventType.ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR and event.args and event.args['is_fatal']:
        sys.exit(1)


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    credentials = auth_helpers.get_assistant_credentials()
    with Board() as board, Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
        for event in assistant.start():
            process_event(board.led, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there anywhere you can run the program in order to receive a more detailed error message?

Comment: Not that I know of unfortunately. As far as I know I can only run it in console.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to load an older version of the library for V1 AIY Voice to work.
Try pip3 install google-assistant-library==1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/359#issuecomment-566932704) is the fix I googled.

**Fix from the ref link:**

```
--- env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/assistant/library/assistant.py~      2019-12-18 08:07:00.039021501 +0000
+++ env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/assistant/library/assistant.py       2019-12-18 08:31:35.365685657 +0000
@@ -100,8 +100,7 @@
         self._inst = c_void_p(
             self._lib.assistant_new(
                 self._event_callback,
-                device_model_id.encode('ASCII')))
+                device_model_id.encode('ASCII'), None))

         self._credentials_refresher = CredentialsRefresher(
             credentials, self._set_credentials)
@@ -278,7 +277,7 @@

         # void* assistant_new(EventCallback listener, const char*
         # device_model_id);
-        self._lib.assistant_new.argtypes = [EVENT_CALLBACK, c_char_p]
+        self._lib.assistant_new.argtypes = [EVENT_CALLBACK, c_char_p, c_char_p]
         self._lib.assistant_new.restype = c_void_p

         # void assistant_free(void* instance);
```

Comment: Answers that only contain a link to the solution aren't very useful (the content they link to might change or become inaccessible). Please include important parts in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be helpful but I had the same problem in getting mine to run. On page https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=249368
I found this comment on the same problem:

---

Re: google-assistant-demo and googlesamples-assistant-hotword segmentation fault
Quote
Sun Nov 10, 2019 1:52 pm 
This is due to the deprecated google-assistant-library. The Google Assistant Service no longer supports hotword detection. “Ok Google” and “Hey Google” are no longer supported. There are still options out there to use the library. Check out the aiyprojects-raspbian on github.

The second option is to use another library to convert the speech to text and pass it the the assistant service api. Snowboy looks like a viable option, with what seems like quite a bit of configuration.

---

I did not try Snowboy yet but there seems to be a lot posted on it and people I know have used it.
This page links code that he says works with Snowboy (I have not tried it) 
https://cyber-renegade.org/2017/12/21/aiy-voice-kit-voice-vad-or-hotword-activation/
Hope this helps.